# Determine voltage regulators for a circuit

Tags: voltage, power, motor, voltage-regulator, circuit-design

I'm trying to determine if the switching voltage regulators I want to use in my circuit are suitable.

I want to use the regulators to change a 50V line into a 5V line that supports motors.

The motor has a nominal current of 0.7A. Its stall current is 1.6A.

*I've read that motors draw close to their stall current when starting up, although it is only for a short time.*

**Should I choose my regulators based on stall current or nominal current?**

Thank you for reading, any input would be appreciated.

Comment: It is common practice to always *over dimension* your regulators a bit. If the nominal load current is 0.7 A then a regulator with a maximum output current of 0.7 A has to operate at or very close to its maximum all the time. The regulator might wear out sooner. I suggest that you use a regulator that can "easily" deliver the (higher) stall current so that it never has to operate near its maximum. So I'd choose a regulator that can deliver up to 2 A of output current. If a 3 A regulator is only slightly more expensive, than I would use that, a higher current does not harm.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input

Comment: If you design only for 0.7A consumption, the output voltage will drop momentarily because regulator cannot provide the 1.6A required. If the regulator has an overcurrent limit, it might trigger and shut down, and it won't start with the 1.6A load until it is removed. In practice a suitably large amount of capacitance could be used to provide starting surge to motor even if regulator is not rated for the full 1.6A, but then again it would not start up if the motor is there and the capacitor too. Regulator should be made to provide 1.6A to all motors that are to be started simultaneously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the stall current is 1.6A, then the motor can reach it and/or come close to it during operation under heavy loads. Therefore, you need to be able to deliver that peak current. If possible, go above 1.6A, say 1.8A which gives you extra 12% margin. Always choose your components so that they can withstand critical conditions that may arise during operation, otherwise some unpleasant surprises can occur

Comment: Thank you very much for your input